# scale_shape --> fill 5 shapes in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapes, fill

I would like to include a different colour for my data and also different shapes that are filled.

If I use shapes such as 15,16,17 etc, the shapes are filled. But unfortunately, there are only 4 filled options. I would need 5 filled options. That is why I think that shapes 21-25 would be the best idea, but now I need to fill them...

data:
[example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmimW.png)

```
#definition of dummy data set
set.seed(1)
n <- 12
df2 <- data.frame("parameter1" = runif(n, min=-20.75, max=-18.77),
                  "parameter2" = runif(n, min=-162.4, max=-143.9),
                  "parameter3" = runif(n, min=-0.2227, max=-0.1378),
                  "parameter4" = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5))

#definition of colour
mycolour_parameter3<-c("#8c510a","#bf812d","#dfc27d","#f6e8c3","#c7eae5","#80cdc1","#35978f","#01665e")

#plot
ggplot(df2,aes(parameter1,parameter2,col=parameter3,shape=factor(parameter4)))+
  geom_point(size=5)+
  scale_colour_gradientn("Parameter3",colours = mycolour_parameter3)+
  scale_shape_manual("Parameter4",values=c(21,22,23,24,25))
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks a lot in advance!
Sandra

Comment: Try with using the `fill` aesthetic instead of `color`, i.e. `ggplot(..., aes(fill = parameter3)) + ... + scale_fill_gradientn(....`.

Comment: That was easy and helped me a lot! Thank you!!